# Obtaining covariate-adjusted prevalence estimates from svyglm() model

Tags: r, stata

So I am interested in calculating covariate-adjusted prevalence using survey data. My question pertains to a specific proprietary dataset, but below is an example using `data(nhanes)` data. I apologize in advance for the length of the post...

**Step #1**

I fit two regression models: (1) a crude model and (2) an adjusted model

```
#Setup
if(!require (survey)) install.packages("survey")
library(survey)

#Read in data
data("nhanes")

#Create survey design
d.obj = svydesign(id = ~SDMVPSU,
                  strata = ~SDMVSTRA,
                  weights = ~WTMEC2YR,
                  nest = TRUE, 
                  data = nhanes)

#Regression models
mod.1 = svyglm(formula = HI_CHOL ~ as.factor(agecat),
               design = d.obj,
               family = quasibinomial(link = "log"))

mod.2 = svyglm(formula = HI_CHOL ~ as.factor(agecat) + as.factor(race) + as.factor(RIAGENDR),
               design = d.obj,
               family = quasibinomial(link = "log"))
```

**Step #2**

I exponentiated the coefficients to obtain the prevalence ratios and 95% CIs. The below summary shows the PRs for the crude model above the "NA" line and the PRs for the adjusted model below the line.

```
#Regression Summary
mod.sum = rbind(cbind("Estimate" = exp(coef(mod.1)), exp(confint(mod.1))),
                c(NA, NA, NA),
                cbind("Estimate" = exp(coef(mod.2)), exp(confint(mod.2))))

> mod.sum
                              Estimate        2.5 %      97.5 %
(Intercept)                0.008660272  0.004735950  0.01583638
as.factor(agecat)(19,39]   9.109573963  4.818424917 17.22229550
as.factor(agecat)(39,59]  20.610647336 10.441625642 40.68320376
as.factor(agecat)(59,Inf] 17.932147454  9.227318351 34.84890193
                                    NA           NA          NA
(Intercept)                0.008597533  0.004623207  0.01598838
as.factor(agecat)(19,39]   9.051050139  4.816409068 17.00883531
as.factor(agecat)(39,59]  20.472879940 10.415264252 40.24274401
as.factor(agecat)(59,Inf] 17.641599353  9.050357148 34.38825923
as.factor(race)2           0.939905542  0.824583833  1.07135550
as.factor(race)3           0.693581683  0.536698646  0.89632339
as.factor(race)4           0.876065546  0.494248225  1.55284491
as.factor(RIAGENDR)2       1.210035838  1.048810926  1.39604451
```

**Step #3**

Prevalence estimation of `HI_CHOL` by age category is fairly simple...

```
#Calculting prevalence of HI_CHOL by agecat
prv = svyby(formula = ~HI_CHOL, by = ~agecat, design = d.obj, FUN = svymean, vartype = "ci", na.rm = TRUE)

> prv
           agecat     HI_CHOL        ci_l       ci_u
(0,19]     (0,19] 0.008660267 0.003433241 0.01388729
(19,39]   (19,39] 0.078891392 0.061116023 0.09666676
(39,59]   (39,59] 0.178493821 0.156964219 0.20002342
(59,Inf] (59,Inf] 0.155297283 0.130664250 0.17993032
```

Using the point estimates from `prv` I can calculate by hand the point estimates from `mod.1` if I use `agecat == (0,19]` as the reference group. However, I wish to calculate the covariate-adjusted prevalence for each age category (such that I could similarly calculate by hand the point estimates from `mod.2` if I again use `agecat == (0,19]` as the reference group). I do not know how to do this.

In Stata, I can run the `margins` command to produce such estimates (or so I believe, but when I run the command on my proprietary data the lower bound of the confidence intervals are negative and I'm not sure how to interpret them).

```
. svyset SDMVPSU [pweight = WTMEC2YR], strata(SDMVSTRA) singleunit(centered)

      pweight: WTMEC2YR
          VCE: linearized
  Single unit: centered
     Strata 1: SDMVSTRA
         SU 1: SDMVPSU
        FPC 1: <zero>

. svy: glm HI_CHOL i.agecat i.race i.RIAGENDR, family(binomial) link(log) eform allbase
(running glm on estimation sample)

Survey: Generalized linear models

Number of strata   =        15                Number of obs     =        7,846
Number of PSUs     =        31                Population size   =  255,345,910
                                              Design df         =           16

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |             Linearized
     HI_CHOL |     exp(b)   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      agecat |
     (0,19]  |          1  (base)
    (19,39]  |   9.051065   2.917803     6.83   0.000     4.569875    17.92648
    (39,59]  |   20.47291   7.054992     8.76   0.000      9.86093    42.50513
   (59,Inf]  |   17.64163   5.994874     8.45   0.000     8.583895    36.25709
             |
        race |
          1  |          1  (base)
          2  |   .9399055   .0616344    -0.95   0.359     .8179215    1.080082
          3  |   .6935817   .0908676    -2.79   0.013     .5253873    .9156208
          4  |   .8760655   .2516647    -0.46   0.651     .4764973    1.610693
             |
    RIAGENDR |
          1  |          1  (base)
          2  |   1.210036   .0872042     2.65   0.018       1.0386    1.409769
             |
       _cons |   .0085975   .0027195   -15.04   0.000     .0043969    .0168111
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. margins agecat, expression(exp(predict(xb))) vce(unconditional)

Predictive margins

Number of strata   =        15                Number of obs     =        7,846
Number of PSUs     =        31                Population size   =  255,345,910
                                              Design df         =           16

Expression   : exp(predict(xb))

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |             Linearized
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      agecat |
     (0,19]  |   .0087239    .002677     3.26   0.005     .0030489    .0143989
    (19,39]  |   .0789607    .009204     8.58   0.000      .059449    .0984724
    (39,59]  |   .1786039   .0107848    16.56   0.000     .1557412    .2014666
   (59,Inf]  |    .153904   .0129656    11.87   0.000     .1264183    .1813898
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Additional Context**

In my above `nhanes` example the point-estimates between the crude and adjusted models do not meaningfully differ. However, with my proprietary data, the analogous "crude" model is more of a "minimally-adjusted model" that takes the form `outcome ~ exposure + covar` where `covar` is a structural covariate that is not accounted for when setting the survey design. If I were to calculate outcome prevalence by exposure group traditionally without accounting for `covar` the resulting estimate would not be meaningful. Given this, the only way I know how to calculate prevalence would be based off a regression model (like I did in Stata), but I don't know how to do this in R and would really like to learn.

**UPDATE 3/21/2021**

So I believe I have solved the issue code-wise, but interpreting the results has me scratching my head. In short, I can group by exposure and sum the exponentiated model-fitted values for each permutation of covariates. I was able to do this using the `nhanes` as follows:

```
#Setup
library(survey)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

#Read in data
data("nhanes")

#Factoring covariates
nhanes$race %<>% factor()
nhanes$RIAGENDR %<>% factor()

#Create survey design
d.obj = svydesign(id = ~SDMVPSU,
                  strata = ~SDMVSTRA,
                  weights = ~WTMEC2YR,
                  nest = TRUE, 
                  data = nhanes)

#Regression models
mod.1 = svyglm(formula = HI_CHOL ~ agecat,
               design = d.obj,
               family = quasibinomial(link = "log"))

mod.2 = svyglm(formula = HI_CHOL ~ agecat + race + RIAGENDR,
               design = d.obj,
               family = quasibinomial(link = "log"))

#Regression Summary
mod.sum =
  list(Model.1 = data.frame(tidy(mod.1, exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE)),
       Model.2 = data.frame(tidy(mod.2, exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE)))

#Appending regression fitted values to data frame
df.1 = augment(mod.1)
df.2 = augment(mod.2)

#Estimating probabilities for each permutation of regression formula
x.prob.1 = aggregate(cbind(est= exp(.fitted)) ~ agecat, data = df.1, FUN = mean)
x.prob.2 = aggregate(cbind(est= exp(.fitted)) ~ race + RIAGENDR + agecat, data = df.2, FUN = mean)

#Estimating probability of outcome given exposure, independant of covars
tab.x.1 = aggregate(est~ agecat, data = x.prob.1, FUN = sum)
tab.x.1 %<>% mutate(rr = est/est[1])

tab.x.2 = aggregate(est~ agecat, data = x.prob.2, FUN = sum)
tab.x.2 %<>% mutate(rr = est/est[1])

#Summarizing tab.x
tab.x.sum = list(Model.1 = tab.x.1, Model.2 = tab.x.2)

#Estimating prevalence through traditional method
prev = svyby(formula = ~HI_CHOL, by = ~agecat, design = d.obj, FUN = svymean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

The results of the summary objects are below...

```
> mod.sum
$Model.1
            term     estimate std.error  statistic      p.value    conf.low   conf.high
1    (Intercept)  0.008660272 0.3079463 -15.421547 9.802627e-10  0.00473595  0.01583638
2  agecat(19,39]  9.109573963 0.3249442   6.799094 1.264216e-05  4.81842492 17.22229550
3  agecat(39,59] 20.610647336 0.3469490   8.721189 8.585730e-07 10.44162564 40.68320376
4 agecat(59,Inf] 17.932147454 0.3389994   8.515045 1.122087e-06  9.22731835 34.84890193

$Model.2
            term     estimate  std.error   statistic      p.value     conf.low   conf.high
1    (Intercept)  0.008597533 0.31652962 -15.0263347 1.111045e-07  0.004623207  0.01598838
2  agecat(19,39]  9.051050139 0.32186925   6.8440237 7.523606e-05  4.816409068 17.00883531
3  agecat(39,59] 20.472879940 0.34481686   8.7556654 1.068803e-05 10.415264252 40.24274401
4 agecat(59,Inf] 17.641599353 0.34054477   8.4284357 1.455588e-05  9.050357148 34.38825923
5          race2  0.939905542 0.06678723  -0.9279602 3.776433e-01  0.824583833  1.07135550
6          race3  0.693581683 0.13083519  -2.7965432 2.082994e-02  0.536698646  0.89632339
7          race4  0.876065546 0.29204774  -0.4530573 6.612323e-01  0.494248225  1.55284491
8      RIAGENDR2  1.210035838 0.07295691   2.6131862 2.812343e-02  1.048810926  1.39604451

> tab.x.sum
$Model.1
    agecat         est        rr
1   (0,19] 0.008660272  1.000000
2  (19,39] 0.078891392  9.109574
3  (39,59] 0.178493821 20.610647
4 (59,Inf] 0.155297283 17.932147

$Model.2
    agecat       est       rr
1   (0,19] 0.0666845  1.00000
2  (19,39] 0.6035648  9.05105
3  (39,59] 1.3652238 20.47288
4 (59,Inf] 1.1764213 17.64160

> prev
           agecat     HI_CHOL          se
(0,19]     (0,19] 0.008660267 0.002666899
(19,39]   (19,39] 0.078891392 0.009069233
(39,59]   (39,59] 0.178493821 0.010984693
(59,Inf] (59,Inf] 0.155297283 0.012568105
```

There are a few (if not many) problems with this approach. First, the log-binomial point estimates from R don't align with the ones from STATA, though this can probably be attributed to underling procedural differences. Second for R, while the prevalence estimates and their corresponding prevalence ratios add up, the estimates for the adjusted model don't make sense. For instance, `tab.x.sum$Model.2` has prevalence estimates above 1.00! This leads me to believe that, while I have mathematically/code-wise solved my issue, the estimands I've produced are something entirely different than I thought they were.

Any insight into what I've actually calculated would be helpful...!